# Intermittant JavaScript Error in DevExpress

Tags: c#, javascript

I am getting an intermittent JavaScript error when using the DevExpress client API.  This error can sometimes occur on one computer when all other computers are running the code perfectly fine.

The error is:

```
"Unhandled exception at line 70, column1 in http://localhost:4593/Home/Grid.  JavaScript runtime error: 'MVCxClientGridView' is undefined."
```

The error occurs at the following line in the compiled code:

```
var dxo = new MVCxClientGridView('GridView');
```

I have not been able to successfully replicate the causes of the error - it sort of just goes away after awhile.  What am I missing?

Comment: You might be better to create a smaller project that reproduces the error and getting in contact with DevExpress help guys directly. We can't help you without much more information.

Comment: Any chance it could be a timing error? - are you sure the devexpress scripts are loaded when you make that call?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it.  It seems to occur when I change Client API variable names - I am thinking that there must be a cache somewhere saving the old names - where could this be?